# Shared Element transition-Error

Tags: android

Hi I'm new to the android,I have created application where i used shared element transition but i'm facing an error in below line of code:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options =

    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                    viewStart,   // Starting view
                    transitionName    // The String
            );
```

showing as:

> The method makeSceneTransitionAnimation(LearnView, TextView, String)
>   is undefined for the type ActivityOptionsCompat

at the same time I have an error in my appcompat_v7(Values-v23) showing as:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse
>
> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored

And i have recently update my sdk to Marshmallow(23).Can anyone please tell what went wrong and how to solve both this error,Thanks in Advance

Comment: check your app's build.gradle file it must have `  compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` after updating

Comment: Hi Anup,i'm using eclipse

Comment: Should I want to change my build target to 23 ?